# Google Cloud SDK v274.0.0 update asking for Python 2.7 interpreter on a machine that has only ever had Python 3+ (Windows)

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

This is really strange - I've found no help in the documentation, nor can we replicate the error on a machine of a similar build. The `gcloud` CLI has worked without any error on my Python 3 machine for months.

After today's update, any `gcloud` command is met with the below error message, looking for a Python 2.7 interpreter. I'm at a loss as to how to proceed - even when attempting to uninstall with the `gcloud` command the same error is thrown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that is being tracked [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146458519)

Version 2.74 installation is broken on Windows. You will need to install an older version. This can be fixed by hand-editing `gcloud.cmd` but I do not recommend this.

Use the following link to download a previous version after uninstalling the current version.

[Installing from versioned archives](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives)

[UPDATE 12/30/2019]

Google has released a minor revision update that appears to fix this problem. The revised update is version 2.74.0.1.